# Executing bash script in remote server through a Jenkins's shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, remote-access

I was trying to execute a script in a remote server through a Jenkins job shell script. When I executed, the build was successful but I don't get the expected output. The parameter called "war_files_to_add" is taken from the Jenkins job parameter. And also "DEV1" variable is the IP address of the remote server. Also note that below code in the same Jenkins job, build stage.
Note :- Jenkins is running on ***DEV2*** server.

**example value for "war_files_to_add"**

```
"polling,processing"
```

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash

WAR_FILES_TO_ADD=${war_files_to_add}

ssh -t centos@$DEV1 bash -c "'

IFS="," read -r -a array <<< "$WAR_FILES_TO_ADD"
for e in "${array[@]}"; do 
    echo "$e"
done

echo "${array[0]}"

'"
```

When I run the below code in my local environment, I get the relevant output.

```
IFS="," read -r -a array <<< "$WAR_FILES_TO_ADD"
for e in "${array[@]}"; do 
    echo "$e"
done

echo "${array[0]}"
```

**OutPut**

```
polling
processing
```

I went through lots of questions and answers here but couldn't find a proper solution. So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does the result you get from jenkins differs from your local test ?

Comment: @Zeitounator- it doesn't print any outputs but the build was successful.

Comment: Not necessarily an error, but certainly odd: You use `war_files_to_add` to access the Jenkins parameter. Environment variables are conventionally all-uppercase, and I would not rule out the possibility that Jenkins secretly converts its parameters to uppercase, when turning them into environment variables. What happens, if you change the statement to set your variable into i.e. `: ${WAR_FILES_TO_ADD:=$war_files_to_add`? (Don't forget the colon in front!)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can create pipeline instead of freestyle project which you can write declarative or scripted pipelines.

What you need is to install [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/) plugin into jenkins, and then write a script like below.

```
def remote = [:]
remote.name = 'test'
remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
remote.user = 'root'
remote.password = 'password'
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
stage('Remote SSH') {
  sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -lrt"
  sshCommand remote: remote, command: "for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done"
}
```

Comment: The script that I was trying to execute was a bit larger than the one I mentioned above. I used this one before.